# Paginação Spring Boot com método de consulta SQL personalizado

Tags: spring-boot, paginação

Seguinte, tenho uma aplicação Spring Boot em que eu faço uma listagem de algumas entidades. Eu pesquisei como usar paginação, porém todos os exemplos que encontrei usam o método padrão `findAll()` do Repository, só que eu não uso esse método na minha aplicação, eu tenho um método próprio em que faço consultas SQL na mão de acordo com parâmetros recebidos (são filtros no *front*, nome igual a alguma coisa, idade menor que alguma coisa, etc..), alguém sabe como usar paginação sem usar o `findAll(`) OU usando `findAll()` mas que possa aplicar filtros no SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Veja um exemplo usando `Query` e `PageRequest`, com uma entidade fictícia chamada `Pessoa` no qual eu uso JPQL:

```
public interface PessoaCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Pessoa, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Pessoa p WHERE p.nome = ?1")
    Page<Pessoa> buscarPessoa(String nomePessoa, Pageable pageable);
}
```

E para chamar e usar:

```
int numeroPagina = 0;
int numeroResultados = 10;
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(numeroPagina, numeroResultados,
            Sort.Direction.ASC, "nome");

Page<Pessoa> pagePessoa = repository.buscarPessoa("Jonas", pageRequest);
List<Pessoa> pessoas = pagePessoa.getContent();
```

Se você deseja usar a notação por nome de método para criar as consultas (sem escrever o JPQL), você pode escrever apenas:

```
public interface PessoaCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Pessoa, Long> {
    Page<Pessoa> findByNome(String nomePessoa, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Se nenhuma das soluções acima atender, dependendo da complexidade da sua consulta, você ter que partir para algo mais flexível usando a classe `Query` e abrindo mão da paginação do Spring e manipulando a `String` da consulta conforme os filtros. Você pode até continuar usando o `PageRequest` como classe para passar os dados de paginação (para não fugir do padrão do seu código), mas a aplicação dele no seu método deve ser **explícita** na `Query`. Exemplo:

```
String jpql = "SELECT p FROM Pessoa p WHERE p.nome = :nome";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql); 
query.setParameter("nome", "Jonas");

query.setFirstResult(pageRequest.getPageNumber() * pageRequest.getPageSize());
query.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());

List<Pessoa> pessoas = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente vc deve verificar qual o select para paginação que o seu banco utiliza.

Oracle:

```
 select * from (
        select  p.id,p.name, rownum as rn
        from Pessoa p
            where rownum <= #{pageNumber} + #{pageSize}
            and p.name like ('%Test')
    ) where rn > #{pageNumber}
```

Postgres:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,
FROM p.name like ('%Test')
LIMIT #{pageSize}
OFFSET(#{pageNumber} - 1) * #{pageSize}
```

No spring boot podemos utilizar da seguinte forma :

```
   import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
   import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
   import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

   public Page<Pessoa> listPessoaByName(String name, Pageable pageable) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("pageSize", pageable.getPageSize());
map.put("pageNumber",pageable.getPageSize()*pageable.getPageNumber());

    //lista as Pessoas de acordo com o select acima.
    // O map representa os parametros que o select ira receber.
    List<Pessoa> listPessoa =  selectList("searchPessoas", map);
    //count com o total de Pessoa que possuem o name
    int total = totalOfPessoaByName(pessoaFilter);
    return new PageImpl<>(listPessoa, pageable,total);
}
```

Caso, a função acima não esteja muito clara, vc pode começar o estudo testando o select pura no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você pode usar pageable com specification.
Projeto de exemplo no github https://github.com/marcospds/h2-api-pageable-jpa-specification-sample

Exemplo metodos no controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = DroidController.PATH, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class DroidController {

    public static final String PATH = "api/v1/droid";

    @Autowired
    private DroidRepository droidRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/findAll")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Droid> findAllDroids() {
        return droidRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/findByName/{name}")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Slice<Droid> findDroidByName(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        Specification<Droid> specs = Specification.where(DroidSpecification.nameEq(name));
        return droidRepository.findAll(specs, pageable);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/findLike/{function}")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Slice<Droid> findDroidLikeDescription(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable, @PathVariable("function") String function) {
        Specification<Droid> specs = Specification.where(DroidSpecification.functionLike(function));
        return droidRepository.findAll(specs, pageable);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de repository:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DroidRepository extends JpaRepository<Droid, Integer>{
    Slice<Droid> findAll(Specification<Droid> specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Exemplo de specification:

```java
public class DroidSpecification {

    public static Specification<Droid> nameEq(String name) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("name"), name);
    }

    public static Specification<Droid> functionLike(String function) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("function")), likeConstructor(function));
    }
}
```

Exemplo no swagger:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]